# Python treatment of integers starting with 0?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm relatively new to Python but typically find it fairly easy to work out. I've just encountered something, though, which has thrown me a little.

I know that type-checking is not very Pythonic but I'm dealing with user-input and it seems useful here. I expected the following code (in Python 2.7.6) to change a non-relevant input to an empty string, but while trying it out in an interactive interpreter, it returned an unexpected int. Could anybody tell me if this is a special value in Python, or explain why this happens.

I thought that perhaps "code" may be the name of a reserved variable ie. one used internally, but changing the name seemed to have no result.

```
>>> code = 0134
>>> if type(code) is not int: code =""
... 
>>> code
92
```

I'm sure I can find an alternative way to do what I'm trying to do here, so that's not so much the focus. I'd simply like to work out what's happening with the unexpected int.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> code = 0134
```

In python 2.7.6 this defines the octal number 132 because of the leading 0. This is equal to the decimal 92.

```
>>> if type(code) is not int: code =""
```

If it's not an int then you clear it.

```
>>> code = 0134
>>> type(code)
<type 'int'>
```

As you can see you do have an int. When you print it out you get the base-10 representation which is 92.

This particular cause of confusion led to the following PEP http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/

Answer (score 1):

When a number begins with a 0 in Python, it is interpreted as an octal number.  0134 in octal is 92 in decimal.

I'm not sure why you think the type of that value will not be int.  It is an integer.